# How does DECODE know what to evaluate when all values in it are VarChar values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some really basic experience with SQL, but I am trying to wrap my head around several hundred lines of SQL we've inherited. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this piece regarding DECODE.

Here's a simplified version of the issue which I'm hoping is enough to illustrate what's going on.

```
    <Tons of subqueries here ... > 
    SELECT <bunch of columns>, 
           DECODE(metric_name,         
           'a_capacity', 'b_capacity', 
           'c_capacity', 'd_capacity',
           'total_a_locations', 'some_b_locations', 
           'total_num_pops', 'pops', 
           'num_rrr_pops','pops', metric_name) 
AS metric_name
    FROM final_intermediate_table
```

The creation of final_intermediate_table is really hairy, but overall its the union of a bunch of other tables into a set of columns and I see that the 'metric_name'  column is set like `'b_capacity' AS metric_name` in some tables in the union, and something like `SUBSTRING(attribute_name, CHARINDEX('_', attribute_name) + 1)::text AS metric_name` in other tables in the union.

I don't really get most of it yet, but I just want to get the DECODE part at this point. What is it actually doing? I know the basic purpose of DECODE from tutorials ([example](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-comparison-functions/sql-decode/)), but a lot of the examples I've seen are comparing values of numbers and then the result is a string value. However, for my dataset, everything is a string value so how does it know what's being compared and what is a result to return? What is this actually trying to do?

Any help so I can wrap my head around this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK `DECODE` is an Oracle thing [Decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE)

Comment: If I'm following the `expr(metric_name)` is compared to each of the search terms(the first value in the pairs(`'a_capacity', 'b_capacity', ...`) so 'a_capacity' and then returns the result if it matches e.g. 'b_capacity'. In the case of no match then the `default`, in your example `metric_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/DECODE.html) is just another way of writing a [`case`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html) expression in SQL. (`decode` handles nulls slightly differently, but there aren't any in your example.)

So, this:

```
decode(metric_name,         
       'a_capacity',        'b_capacity', 
       'c_capacity',        'd_capacity',
       'total_a_locations', 'some_b_locations', 
       'total_num_pops',    'pops', 
       'num_rrr_pops',      'pops',
                            metric_name)
```

is the same as this:

```
case metric_name       
    when  'a_capacity'        then 'b_capacity'
    when  'c_capacity'        then 'd_capacity'
    when  'total_a_locations' then 'some_b_locations'
    when  'total_num_pops'    then 'pops'
    when  'num_rrr_pops'      then 'pops'
    else metric_name
end
```

I don't quite follow what issue you are having with the datatype, as it doesn't affect the logic unless there is some type conversion involved. Like `case`, it will handle all the basic datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

You could reformat the SQL to be clearer regarding how `DECODE` works:

```
SELECT metric_name original_metric_name
, DECODE(metric_name,         
         'a_capacity', 'b_capacity', 
         'c_capacity', 'd_capacity',
         'total_a_locations', 'some_b_locations', 
         'total_num_pops', 'pops', 
         'num_rrr_pops','pops', 
         metric_name) AS metric_name

FROM final_intermediate_table
```

Here is some likely output

| original_metric_name | metric_name |
| --- | --- |
| a_capacity | b_capacity |
| c_capacity | d_capacity |
| total_a_locations | some_b_locations |
| total_num_pops | pops |
| num_rrr_pops | pops |
| another metric name | another metric name |

Comment: Ah, so is it just always the first arg (a1) is the thing to compare stuff against, the second arg (a2) is a potential value, the next arg is the value to return if a1 == a2, and then same goes for the rest of the args until the final piece which is just a1 again - in which case it's just saying if it doesn't match anything (a2, a4, a6, a8, or a10), just return the original a1?